# How to validate custom category attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, category-attribute

How to validate a new custom category attribute in Magento, so that no more than 300 words can be written in that new field?

Is that possible? How could I achieve this? Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating you category attribute like ...

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'group'             => 'General Information',
    'label'             => 'Some Description',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'input'             => 'textarea',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => ''
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'your_attribute_code', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

add this two lines to your attribute data:

```
    'frontend_class'    => 'validate-length maximum-length-300',
    'note'              => 'Maximum length 300 characters',
```

This will enables Magentos form validation and disallow saving more then 300 characters from backend.

---

**Update:**

To have a visual feedback how many characters are left, you can add a JS file to your admin pages. It will display a character counter for every input field that has CSS classes `validate-length` and `maximum-length-XXX`:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_charactercounter>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>admin-charactercounter.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_charactercounter>

    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <update handle="adminhtml_charactercounter"/>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>

    <adminhtml_system_config_edit>
        <update handle="adminhtml_charactercounter"/>
    </adminhtml_system_config_edit>

    <!--
    add other handles
    ...
    -->
</layout>
```

Just add the layout handles for other pages where you need it ...

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    Element.addMethods({
        prepare_for_countdown: function(element) {
            var elm = $(element);
            if(!elm.retrieve('counter')) {
                var counter = new Element('span');
                elm.next('.note').insert(counter);
                elm.store('counter', counter);
                var maxLen = elm.className.match(/maximum-length-(\d+)/)[1];
                elm.store('maxLen', maxLen);
            }
            return elm;
        },
        countdown: function(element) {
            var elm = $(element);
            var curLen = elm.getValue().length;
            var maxLen = elm.retrieve('maxLen');
            var count  = maxLen - curLen;
            var counter = elm.retrieve('counter');
            if (curLen >= maxLen) {
                counter.update(' (' + count + ')').setStyle({'color': 'red'});
            } else {
                counter.update(' (+' + count + ')').setStyle({'color': 'green'});
            }
            return elm;
        }
    });

    $$('.validate-length').invoke('prepare_for_countdown').invoke('countdown');

    document.on('keyup', '.validate-length', function(evt, elm) {
        elm.countdown();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I have tried to update the file mysql4-upgrade-0.1-1.0.php, by adding extra information, but the changes do not take effect on the frontend (have cleaned and flushed the caches, but still no extra changes to see). Do you know how come this?

Comment: Have you change your extensions version in `config.xml` to `1.0` too, to trigger your update script? To check if its working you can also add `frontend_class` in `eav_attribute` table manually.